# Cross-platform solution for Twitter's Oauth using PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, twitter, cross-platform

I'm doing a research about PhoneGap and cross-platform development of mobile apps using HTML 5 and hybrid frameworks. My question is: Is there a way to develop an truly cross-platform application that uses Twitter's Oauth to retrieve data from authorized-only API calls?

When I searched the web I find a few solutions but these were platform dependent. Apparently it's possible to develop such an application for iOS or Android using various PhoneGap plugins and hacks which is really cool. But I'm looking for a truly "write once use everywhere" solution. Is it possible or should I give up?

Thanks for any answer.